How to do a transaction of an NFT, and also update the memo! In python preferably
Well basically I want to transfer an NFT, and add something in the memo using python. TypeScript works as well but Python is preferred!.
I've been researching for the past few days, no luck, all the libraries and the snippets I find are deprecated!. Point me to some docs, and a few code snippets please!.

GOTO solution would be to combine the two instructions, one for memo and the other for the transfer to one transaction.
